# Etymological development of forms of Spanish "seguir" from Latin "SEQVI" (*sequire)

Tags: etymology, romance-languages, spanish

I am seeking an explanation for the development of the forms of Spanish "seguir" from Latin "SEQVI" (Vulgar Latin: *sequire), especially the irregular forms.

Especially, why did the "e" become "i" in the first syllable in some forms?

I have read that it is because of the yod that follows it, causing the vowel "e" to be raised to "i".

For example, in *sequivit > siguió (pretérito tercera persona/preterite third-person):

- *sequivit [ˈsɛkᶣiwit] > /ˈsɛgiwt/ > /sɛˈgiwt/ > /sɛˈgiut/ > /sɛˈgjut/ > /siˈgjot/ (yod-raising) > [siˈɣjo] siguió

However, some of the forms did not have the yod, e.g. VL. *sequis > Sp. sigues. What is it that caused the raising of those forms?

Comment: Latin short *e* becomes *ie* (normally) or *i* (especially in *-ir* verbs) in Spanish when stressed — that happens only in the *yo/tú/él/ellos* forms, but doesn't in the *vos/nosotros/vosotros* forms.  All the verbs that display the jod raising you note undergo this change in the present indicative and subjunctive (with either *ie* or *i*) and *also* undergo an identical (*i* only) change in the present subjunctive *nosotros/vosotros* form, but given that those combinations go with *-amos/-áis*, I'm not sure we can call it jod raising per se (o>ue -ir verbs do the same thing, but to u)

Comment: What is the mechanism of *e* becoming *i* when stressed? I know that it can become *ie* due to vowel breaking, but why *i*? I have read from [this page](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/hisverb.htm), which says "it is the [j] in this sequence that accounts for the raising of the root vowel throughout the imperfect subjunctive in verbs like *dormir* and *pedir*". So, can we agree that it is yod raising when unstressed, and it is that mechanism when stressed?